# What is the difference between Adapter and Fixture Adapter and REST Adapter, in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the difference between Adapter and Fixture Adapter and REST Adapter, and when to use each one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `DS.FixtureAdapter` (or `DS.FixtureAdapter.create()`) when you don't (yet?) care to communicate with a backend, but will store your data as "fixtures" in the client. Once you've declared a model:

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  // ...
});
```

You can define your fixtures:

```
App.Thing.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: '...',
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: '...',
    // ...
  },
];
```

And then you can use the ember-data methods on them (e.g. `App.Thing.findAll()`, etc.) and manipulate them, but of course it will only persist as long as the page does (i.e. the javascript environment).

`DS.RestAdapter`, usable though apparently still under development, was designed to fit well with a Rails API, but could probably be modified / extended to work with whatever RESTful API you're working with. It knows to process `App.Thing.findAll()` by making a call to `/things`, and to process `App.Thing.find(12)` with a call to `/things/12`. This is a relative path, appended to the namespace parameter you pass in:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RestAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'http://what.ever/api/v1'
  })
});
```

`DS.Adapter` is rather abstract: the superclass of the aforementioned built-in Adapters. If neither suit your needs, you may well want to implement your own:

```
App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    // ...
    jQuery.get( ... , function(data) {
      store.load(type, id, data);
    });
  },
  createRecord: function(store, type, model) {
    // ...
    jQuery.post( ... , function(data) {
      store.didCreateRecord(model, data);
    });
  },
  // ...
});
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: App.adapter
});
```

Hope that helps. See the readme doc at https://github.com/emberjs/data for more information.