# Ember.js Create simple, non persistent datastore

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datastore

How to implement a simple non persistent datastore in ember? I've tried to follow the [Article of Jiri Zajpt](http://jzajpt.github.com/2012/01/24/emberjs-app-architecture-data.html) but somehow i can't figure out how it's working. I think i need a deeper understanding of the datastore concept.

As i understand the concept correctly, the datastore provides methods to deal with data and storing these data into an application wide accessible object, right?

This is what i've so far:

#### Ember App

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.DataSource = Ember.Object.extend({
    store : null,
    getTickets: function(callback) {
        var store = this.store;
        jQuery.get('/data/tickets.json', function(data) {
            store.pushObjects(data);
            callback(store);
        });
    }
});

App.dataSource = App.DataSource.create({
    store: App.store
});

App.Store = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
        this._super();
    }
});

App.store = App.Store.create();​
```

#### Loaded JSON

```
[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "type":"bug",
    "prority":"normal",
    "status":"open",
    "title":"Router is stopping at a non-leaf state",
    "discription":"Lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "type":"Change request",
    "prority":"normal",
    "status":"open",
    "title":"Add Ember.Deferred mixin",
    "discription":"Lorem ipsum"
    }
]
```

Note: The code above has currently no output. Here is a Fiddle to play with: **http://jsfiddle.net/WHqVJ/**

I know the ember-data project but i think it's a little bit to much for my project and also i want to learn to create a datastore.

Comment: Considering using [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)? The `fixtureAdapter` is what you want. This might clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11911954/363073

Comment: Oh yes... i've read this post. Also the `ember-data` documentation. But i want to understand the concept of a datastore… and as mentioned in my question i think it's too much overhead for a small project. Don't you think so?!

Comment: Well I'm not sure, but since you ask, I'd just note that if ember (137KB) isn't too much overhead, then ember-data (36KB) isn't likely to be. The learning curve for ember-data is pretty steep so it might help to start trying it out for small projects (and in particular, with the fixtureAdapter). But avoiding it to better learn the concepts that it implements is also something I can understand. (Sorry, missed the note about ember-data in the question)